# React Native: AWS Cognito Auth.federatedSignIn() not waiting for auth result

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, google-sso

I am trying to implement Google Sign-In using AWS Amplify in a React Native project. After the user signs in, I want to set the current authenticated user as Amplify.Auth.currentUser. However, I'm facing a few issues with the current implementation:

The Auth.federatedSignIn function doesn't seem to wait for the user to be fully authenticated before moving on to the next line of code, resulting in the current authenticated user not being set correctly.

```ts
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider } from '@aws-amplify/auth/lib/types';

const user = await Auth.federatedSignIn({
  provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google,
});
```

Exception raised: **Error signing in with Google: The user is not authenticated**

The Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser function also doesn't return the current authenticated user, even when I wait for a few seconds after the user signs in.

The error message in the catch block of the signInWithGoogle function says "The user is not authenticated", even though the user is successfully authenticated and the redirectURL is fired with the user token. (Since I set a **redirectSignIn** URL, my app was able to log and receive the **#token**)

I would appreciate any help in resolving these issues so that I can correctly set the current authenticated user after the user signs in using Google Sign-In.